# Returning a typed let value from Typescript async await method?

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following code inside my main file for a command line app:

```
const init = async (): Promise<types.IContextObject> => {
  let context: types.IContextObject;
  try {
      context = await createContext(dataObj);
  } catch (e) {
      dataObj.errors.insert({ message: e.message });
      process.exit(1);
  }

  context.info.insert({
    message: `Using Rules: `.bold + `${Object.keys(context.rules).join(', ')}`
  });
  return context;
```

};

In this I get the following compiler error:

```
Variable 'context' is used before being assigned.
let context: types.IContextObject
```

If I move the last two lines inside the try block I get:

```
Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put it outside the try, there's no guarantee that value exists. If you put it in the try, you have to provide a second return method, so that it returns something when the try fails.

So either you provide a default value for `context` or you provide a default return statement at the bottom. Either of these works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `context` is undefined outside of the try block. Either move your insert and return inside of the try block and return null in your catch, or set `context` to null when you declare it; however, if you do the latter without proper null checks after your catch statement, it could throw an error when attempting to access `info`.